# True or False: Fenchel dual $f^*$ is strictly convex if and only if $f$ is strictly concave?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, examples-counterexamples, nonlinear-optimization

It is trivial to see that the [Fenchel conjugate/dual](https://people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/68.pdf) given by

$$f^*(y) = \sup\limits_{x \in X}\{x^Ty - f(x)\}$$ of any function $f$ is convex.

Is it true (as a necessarily and sufficient condition) that if $f$ is strictly concave, then $f^*$ is strictly convex?

Are there less restrictive conditions under which the dual $f^*$ is strictly convex?

Comment: Why strictly _concave_? Conjugates are typically considered for convex functions. Besides, consider $f(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}x^2$...

Comment: @MichaelGrant   You meant $  f(x)= - \tfrac{1}{2}x^2$  ?

Comment: No. Conjugates are for convex functions. $f^*=f$ in that case.

Comment: I actually think there is a relationship between strictly _convex_ functions and their conjugates. In particular, when the function is twice differentiable as well, the Hessians have a certain inverse relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No in general!

Take $f(x)= - \tfrac{1}{2}x^2$  clearly $f$ is strictly concave but $f^*(y) = + \infty$ for all $y \in \Bbb R$. Which I don't think is considered as strictly convex function!

Mabey you need impose condition like boundedness!